# ldap queries in Qt

Tags: qt, ldap, qml

Thinking of implementing a LDAP-viewer in QML. The first step is obviously to make a Qt back-end that can handle ldap-queries. I've read the rfc1823 (ldap tutorial of sorts), but still can't understand where to begin really.

I would be interested in some Qt code that would get me started on some sample LDAP functions, for instance :

1. connect to a ldap server
2. do some simple query of any type
3. close the connection

Edit: code is not required if you can point me to any tutorials/guides as to how one does this in C++ / Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using libldap. Writing a client from scratch is a lot of work. Take a look [here](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2003/08/14/libldap.html) for some examples as a kick-off. You can easily integrate that code with Qt.

The [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) library also has some c++ [example](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/ldapc%2b%2b/examples/main.cpp;hb=HEAD) included.